# Is there a JavaScript implementation of cl100k_base tokenizer?

Tags: node.js, machine-learning, nlp, tokenize, openai-api

OpenAI's new embeddings API uses the `cl100k_base` tokenizer. I'm calling it from the Node.js client, but I don't see any easy way of slicing my strings so they don't exceed the OpenAI limit of 8192 tokens.

This would be trivial if I could first encode the string, slice it to the limit, then decode it and send it to the API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@dqbd/tiktoken](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@dqbd/tiktoken) supports the `cl100k_base` encoding.

Comment: Woohoo! Thanks to @dqbd!

Answer (score 4):

**Update**: David Duong created a [JavaScript port](https://github.com/dqbd/tiktoken) of openai/tiktoken with JS/WASM bindings. The package can be installed via npm:

```
npm install tiktoken
```

Credit to Lars Grammel's answer below for the discovery/update.

---

**Original interim solution** (before the aforementioned package was available):

There is a general rule of thumb that one token corresponds to approximately four characters of common English text. This roughly translates to one token being equal to 3/4 of a word. So in your case, a limit of 8,192 tokens ~= 6,144 words. Therefore, you could slice your strings such that they don't exceed ~6,144 words (e.g., set a 6,100 word limit. If that fails, reduce the limit further until you find one that is suitable).